# How to create lazy_evaluated dataframe columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lazy-evaluation

A lot of times, I have a big dataframe `df` to hold the basic data, and need to create many more columns to hold the derivative data calculated by basic data columns.

I can do that in Pandas like:

```
df['derivative_col1'] = df['basic_col1'] + df['basic_col2']
df['derivative_col2'] = df['basic_col1'] * df['basic_col2']
....
df['derivative_coln'] = func(list_of_basic_cols)
```

etc. Pandas will calculate and allocate the memory for all derivative columns all at once.

What I want now is to have a lazy evaluation mechanism to postpone the calculation and memory allocation of derivative columns to the actual need moment. Somewhat define the lazy_eval_columns as:

```
df['derivative_col1'] = pandas.lazy_eval(df['basic_col1'] + df['basic_col2'])
df['derivative_col2'] = pandas.lazy_eval(df['basic_col1'] * df['basic_col2'])
```

That will save the time/memory like Python 'yield' generator, for if I issue `df['derivative_col2']` command will only triger the specific calculation and memory allocation.

So how to do `lazy_eval()` in Pandas ? Any tip/thought/ref are welcome.

Comment: Great question. Don't know if pandas have such a thing, though. The idea reminds me SQL computed columns in views.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting in 0.13 (releasing very soon), you can do something like this. This is using generators to evaluate a dynamic formula. In-line assignment via eval will be an additional feature in 0.13, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5343)

```
In [19]: df = DataFrame(randn(5, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
          a         b
0 -1.949107 -0.763762
1 -0.382173 -0.970349
2  0.202116  0.094344
3 -1.225579 -0.447545
4  1.739508 -0.400829

In [21]: formulas = [ ('c','a+b'), ('d', 'a*c')]
```

Create a generator that evaluates a formula using `eval`; assigns the result, then yields the result.

```
In [22]: def lazy(x, formulas):
   ....:     for col, f in formulas:
   ....:         x[col] = x.eval(f)
   ....:         yield x
   ....:
```

In action

```
In [23]: gen = lazy(df,formulas)

In [24]: gen.next()
Out[24]: 
          a         b         c
0 -1.949107 -0.763762 -2.712869
1 -0.382173 -0.970349 -1.352522
2  0.202116  0.094344  0.296459
3 -1.225579 -0.447545 -1.673123
4  1.739508 -0.400829  1.338679

In [25]: gen.next()
Out[25]: 
          a         b         c         d
0 -1.949107 -0.763762 -2.712869  5.287670
1 -0.382173 -0.970349 -1.352522  0.516897
2  0.202116  0.094344  0.296459  0.059919
3 -1.225579 -0.447545 -1.673123  2.050545
4  1.739508 -0.400829  1.338679  2.328644
```

So its user determined ordering for the evaluation (and not on-demand). In theory `numba` is going to support this, so pandas possibly support this as a backend for `eval` (which currently uses numexpr for immediate evaluation).

my 2c.

lazy evaluation is nice, but can easily be achived by using python's own continuation/generate features, so building it into pandas, while possible, is quite tricky, and would need a really nice usecase to be generally useful.

Comment: It is nice to have the 'formula' and eval feature in coming update cersion. And I want to know more about how to use df['lazy_eval_col_x'] syntax to triger the on-demand calculation.

Answer (score 8):

You could subclass `DataFrame`, and add the column as a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). For example,

```
import pandas as pd

class LazyFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    @property
    def derivative_col1(self):
        self['derivative_col1'] = result = self['basic_col1'] + self['basic_col2']
        return result

x = LazyFrame({'basic_col1':[1,2,3],
               'basic_col2':[4,5,6]})
print(x)
#    basic_col1  basic_col2
# 0           1           4
# 1           2           5
# 2           3           6
```

Accessing the property (via `x.derivative_col1`, below) calls the `derivative_col1` function defined in LazyFrame. This function computes the result and adds the derived column to the LazyFrame instance:

```
print(x.derivative_col1)
# 0    5
# 1    7
# 2    9

print(x)
#    basic_col1  basic_col2  derivative_col1
# 0           1           4                5
# 1           2           5                7
# 2           3           6                9
```

Note that if you modify a basic column:

```
x['basic_col1'] *= 10
```

the derived column is **not** automatically updated:

```
print(x['derivative_col1'])
# 0    5
# 1    7
# 2    9
```

But if you access the property, the values are recomputed:

```
print(x.derivative_col1)
# 0    14
# 1    25
# 2    36

print(x)
#    basic_col1  basic_col2  derivative_col1
# 0          10           4               14
# 1          20           5               25
# 2          30           6               36
```

Answer (score 0):

**Before any modification or extension to Pandas' data-structures, prefer using a library to ease the process load like [Dask](https://www.dask.org/) or [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/).**

---

Pandas' [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) suggests some alternatives for extending its data-structures:

> There are some easier alternatives before considering subclassing
> pandas data structures.
>
> - Extensible method chains with [pipe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures)
> - Use composition. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures).
> - Extending by [registering an accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures)
> - Extending by [extension type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures)

### Subclassing pandas.DataFrame

#### Use

Let's assume you already have your `DataFrame` (constructed from the below `CustomDataFrame` class definition) named `df` with populated data (for the sake of this example)

```
def column1_column2_sum(data): return data['column1'] + data['column2']

df[column1_column2_sum.__name__] = column1_column2_sum
```

#### Class definition

**`all_columns` method definition assume only one column level here for simplicity.**

```
from typing import Callable, Dict
import pandas as pd


class CustomDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    _metadata = ["_lazy_columns"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._lazy_columns = {}

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return CustomDataFrame

    @property
    def all_columns(self):
        return list(super().columns) + list(self._lazy_columns.keys())

    def register_lazy_series(self, columns: Dict[str, Callable]):
        self._lazy_columns.update(((self._format_key(key), value)
                                   for key, value in columns.items()))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value) -> None:
        if callable(value):
            return self._lazy_columns.__setitem__(key, value)
        return super().__setitem__(key, value)


    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self._lazy_columns.keys():
            compute = self._lazy_columns[key]
            self[key] = compute(self)
            self._lazy_columns.pop(key)

        return super().__getitem__(key)
```

Feel free to suggest any modification to the above code in the comments.