# How to solve memory error in mtrand.RandomState.choice?

Tags: python

I'm trying to sample 1e7 items from 1e5 strings but getting a memory error. It's fine sampling 1e6 items from 1e4 strings. I'm on a 64bit machine with 4GB RAM and don't think I should be reaching any memory limit at 1e7.  Any ideas?

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.3 (default, Nov 27 2013, 17:12:35) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> K = 100
```

Works fine with 1e6 :

```
>>> N = int(1e6)
>>> np.random.choice(["id%010d"%x for x in range(N//K)], N)
array(['id0000005473', 'id0000005694', 'id0000004115', ..., 'id0000006958',
       'id0000009972', 'id0000003009'], 
      dtype='<U12')
```

Error with N=1e7 :

```
>>> N = int(1e7)
>>> np.random.choice(["id%010d"%x for x in range(N//K)], N)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1092, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:8229)
MemoryError
>>>
```

I found this question but it seems to be about catching an error like this rather than solving it.

[Python not catching MemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899910/python-not-catching-memoryerror)

I'd be happy with either a solution still using `random.choice` or a different method to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: You are allowing resampling, so I can see a work round just using a random number in the interval required.

Comment: @doctorlove Thx. I've tried `['a','b','c'][np.random.choice(2,1)]` and that works for one. But `['a','b','c'][np.random.choice(2,5)]` gives a TypeError. How do I select the strings by the random numbers? I tried `.tolist()` as well, still TypeError.

Comment: things = ['a', 'b', 'c']; [things[x] for x in np.random.choice(2,5)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work round this using a generator function:

```
def item():
    for i in xrange(N):
      yield "id%010d"%np.random.choice(N//K,1)
```

This avoids needing all the items in memory at once.

Comment: Thanks. Have been trying this out. Can I pass a generator to `pandas.DataFrame()`? I'm testing that and not sure it's working.

Comment: I mean the `groupby` on that column returns a generator too. It feels like Pandas did a single grouping rather than reach inside the generator, if that makes sense. So I'm wondering if I need to eval the generator before passing it to Pandas?

Comment: It seems to depend which version of pandas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915941/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-generator or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605537/how-to-create-lazy-evaluated-dataframe-columns-in-pandas

Comment: Thanks again, interesting. Yes I was on version from Ubuntu stable. Have now installed from NeuroDebian and using the latest pandas: v0.14.1. Retesting ...

Comment: Passing the generator into pandas v0.14.1 gives `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`.  That's fine. I didn't expect to be able to. Just need a way to get the generator to generate then?