# Is this the fastest way to group in Pandas?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas

The following code works well. Just checking: am I using and timing Pandas correctly and is there any faster way? Thanks.

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import timeit
>>> pd.__version__
'0.14.1'

def randChar(f, numGrp, N) :
   things = [f%x for x in range(numGrp)]
   return [things[x] for x in np.random.choice(numGrp, N)]

def randFloat(numGrp, N) :
   things = [round(100*np.random.random(),4) for x in range(numGrp)]
   return [things[x] for x in np.random.choice(numGrp, N)]

N=int(1e8)
K=100
DF = pd.DataFrame({
  'id1' : randChar("id%03d", K, N),       # large groups (char)
  'id2' : randChar("id%03d", K, N),       # large groups (char)
  'id3' : randChar("id%010d", N//K, N),   # small groups (char)
  'id4' : np.random.choice(K, N),         # large groups (int)
  'id5' : np.random.choice(K, N),         # large groups (int)
  'id6' : np.random.choice(N//K, N),      # small groups (int)            
  'v1' :  np.random.choice(5, N),         # int in range [1,5]
  'v2' :  np.random.choice(5, N),         # int in range [1,5]
  'v3' :  randFloat(100,N)                # numeric e.g. 23.5749
})
```

Now time 5 different groupings, repeating each one twice to confirm the timing. [I realise `timeit(2)` runs it twice, but then it reports the total. I'm interested in the time of the first and second run separately.] Python uses about 10G of RAM according to `htop` during these tests.

```
>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id1']).agg({'v1':'sum'})"                            ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
5.604133386000285
>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id1']).agg({'v1':'sum'})"                            ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
5.505057081000359

>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg({'v1':'sum'})"                      ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
14.232032927000091
>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg({'v1':'sum'})"                      ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
14.242601240999647

>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id3']).agg({'v1':'sum', 'v3':'mean'})"               ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
22.87025260900009
>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id3']).agg({'v1':'sum', 'v3':'mean'})"               ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
22.393589012999655

>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id4']).agg({'v1':'mean', 'v2':'mean', 'v3':'mean'})" ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
2.9725865330001398
>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id4']).agg({'v1':'mean', 'v2':'mean', 'v3':'mean'})" ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
2.9683854739996605

>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id6']).agg({'v1':'sum', 'v2':'sum', 'v3':'sum'})"    ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
12.776488024999708
>>> timeit.Timer("DF.groupby(['id6']).agg({'v1':'sum', 'v2':'sum', 'v3':'sum'})"    ,"from __main__ import DF").timeit(1)
13.558292575999076
```

Here is system info :

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2500.048
BogoMIPS:              5066.38
Hypervisor vendor:     Xen
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7,16-23
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15,24-31

$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          240G        74G       166G       372K        33M       550M
-/+ buffers/cache:        73G       166G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

I don't believe it's relevant but just in case, the `randChar` function above is a workaround for a memory error in `mtrand.RandomState.choice` :

[How to solve memory error in mtrand.RandomState.choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627161/how-to-solve-memory-error-in-mtrand-randomstate-choice)

Comment: `df.groupby` is pretty well optimized. What alternatives are you considering? The only thing I can think of is to set the `id` columns as the index and then use `df.groupby(level=id_whatever)`.

Comment: @PaulH Thanks I'll try `id` columns as an index. I'm comparing to R's `data.table` (which I maintain).

Comment: oh cool. the other thing i'll mention is that doing this in an IPython Notebook and using the `timeit` magic will probably maintain some of your sanity. http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb#-Some-simple-cell-magics

Comment: @PaulH Nice. Can I point IPython to a server over SSH?

Comment: I believe so, but you might find it too complicated for this exercise: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html. Last comment: also not trivial to set up, but there is an %%R magic for notebooks, so you can run python code and R code from the same interface. There's also a native R kernel in the works if it hasn't been released already.

Comment: One thing I would say, is that it may be worth seeding your random numbers, since (I'm sure you're aware!) they will effect the speed of the groupbys. In the pandas vbench code it explicity tests performance for both dense and sparse groups (no doubt that is *not* the technical term - sorry) as they have different behaviour.

Comment: @AndyHayden Good point. The construction in the question here is a  tough but realistic test in that the groups are thoroughly shuffled in the data. If there is some clustering of the groups then it should be faster due to cache efficiency. Is that what you mean?  'seeding' to me means setting the `random.seed` to get the same series of random numbers each time.

Comment: @MattDowle oops yes, two parts: 1. setting np.random.seed to make times fair/constant ([not done in pandas yet](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8144)), 2. testing different cluster sizes (large vs small groups).

Comment: @AndyHayden Thanks to your comments I've added some items to the [FAQ](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-%3A-Grouping)  On 2) that's already done in this test, for different column types as well. Feel free to edit directly or suggest more tests.

Comment: @MattDowle thanks for putting this together, excited to see the results!

Comment: @AndyHayden Pandas results now added: [benchmarks](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-:-Grouping)

Comment: This is really, *really* nice.

Comment: I would also suggest using IPython, and using it's %timeit function. There are other magic function commands as well, and I have found they do a better job of timing functions or lines of code. http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit

Comment: @NightHallow Thanks. I'll use IPython's %timeit next time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about optimization of working code belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or, why doesn't the OP just answer the question.  It has now been upvoted 39 times and 2000 people have viewed it.  So that answer can just be the question e.g. Yes, this seems to be the fastest way to group in pandas.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to install the iPython shell, you can easily time your code using %timeit. After installing it, instead of typing `python` to launch the python interpreter, you would type `ipython`.

Then you can type your code exactly as you would type it in the normal interpreter (as you did above).

Then you can type, for example:

```
%timeit DF.groupby(['id1']).agg({'v1':'sum'})
```

This will accomplish exactly the same thing as what you've done, but if you're using python a lot I find that this will save you significant typing time :).

Ipython has a lot of other nice features (like `%paste`, which I used to paste in your code and test this, or `%run` to run a script you've saved in a file), tab completion, etc. 
http://ipython.org/