# create a "dynamic" pandas column, calculated on the fly from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm interested in creating a "dynamic" column in a pandas dataframe. The dynamic column's contents contain references to other columns, such that when one is modified the dynamic's values are also.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'source':[1,2,3]})
df['dyn_col'] = ## something magic here that means source*2
df.dyn_col
>>> 2,4,6
df.source = [4,5,6]
df.dyn_col
>>> 8,10,12
```

This could potentially include references to multiple columns, eg A*B

I tried extending `__getitem__` but it got messy quickly (in part (I think)) because the key wasn't present in the columns

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What's the use case for this? This looks like something that could get really messy really quickly.

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to do that, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605537/how-to-create-lazy-evaluated-dataframe-columns-in-pandas) for some attempts.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I have a dataframe which contains measurements as well as things calculated from those measurements, like ratios. There are situations where those measurements are changed, and recalculating all of the ratios etc becomes highly cumbersome.


Theres also the added benefit that the meaning of the column could be more readily understood, by seeing the calculation instead of only the result